# Which of the forms is correct?

Tags: questions

Which of the following should be used?

> "While in office in 2002, Andrew **did not intend to touch** that issue."
>
> "While in office in 2002, Andrew **had no intention of touching** that issue."

Comment: #2 sounds more natural to me.

Comment: Two ways of saying the same thing. Choose one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one: but it should be worded with the year first, then place.

In 2002, while in the office, Andrew **had no intention of touching that issue.**

It mostly depends on the meaning of the sentence really or what happened.

The first form suggests that Andrew touched the issue by mistake while the second mention his apprehension of the issue and therefore avoids it.

The second one sounds more clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, Gabby. Firstly, there is a difference between "in office" and "in the office". Did you _mean_  to write the second version (as in your answer)? Also, "In 2002, while in office" stresses the _year_ Andrew had no intention (incidentally, while he was in office). "While in office in 2002" tells us that his lack of intention occurred _when he held some official position_ , and that, incidentally, this was in 2002. The implications are very different in these two cases.

Comment: @Margana, you made a very good point. I did think about that but the way my teacher used to teach was to put the year first. And sorry if I added "the" before office, its just something that stuck with me and I can't help it. It all falls back to the meaning of the sentence and interpretation really. Also no I didn't mean for him to write my answer as the second version. It was my opinion at the time but I preferred the second one because it added a sense of emphasis to Andrew's choice.

Answer (score 0):

In 2002, whilst in office, Andrew intended to avoid that issue.